# Is there any advantage to async receiving UPD datagrams assuming an external update loop

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, unity-game-engine, udp

Assume that an external update loop exists. To be more concrete, I'm using Unity, which provides a game loop that calls an `Update()` method on my component at regular intervals.

I now wish to receive UDP datagrams via a `System.Net.Sockets.UDPClient` socket. It is my understanding that UDP datagrams are transmitted en bloc, i.e. not streamed.

As such is there any advantage to using the usual async patterns or is using something like the following code entirely sufficient?

```
void Update() {
  // client is an instance of UDPClient
  IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
  while (client.Available > 0) {
    var datagram = client.Receive(endpoint);
    // process the datagram
  }
}
```

The reason I want to avoid a asynchronous solution is that I'm developing for the HoloLens which introduces a whole host of compatibility issues between the Unity Editor (which uses Mono and requires .Net 3.5 compatible code with an (modified) C# 2 syntax) and the HoloLens which requires UWP.

---

The problem I'm having with development for HoloLens is that the HoloLens requires UWP but if I wish to compile my Unity-C#-scripts with Unity I also have to comply with the requirements of the Unity-Editor which uses Mono and seems to support the .NET 3.5 API and C# language in version 2.0 with some enhancements.

So basically I'm forced to write code that is compatible with two platforms; UWP and Unitys version of Mono on the other. At least that is my understanding of the matter. I may very well be completely wrong.

Apart from that there is also the possibility to import precompiled (with VS) libraries into Unity and reference those from my game scripts.

Comment: Code may work but is not good. Does this code compile for hololens? Try a simple build for hololens then let me know. I will leave an answer.

Comment: You don't need to check `Available > 0`. I suppose it actually will not work correctly this way, because as soon there is no data available in the socket right now - your while loop will exit.

Comment: I don't know anything about this HoloLens that you speak of but generally speaking polling is bad. It burns up CPU time and you're much, much better off using event-driven code if you possibly can.

Comment: @AdamBenson [Microsoft HoloLens](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/hololens). My idea was, that if a polling loop already exists perhaps the overhead is not too bad.

Comment: @Evk that is exactly the intention: If, at the time the `Update()` function is called, there is any data available on the socket then receive and process  datagrams until the socket is empty (for now). With the next game step/frame the Update function will be called again to process further messages.

Comment: @PeterE As indicated in the answer from Peter you're more likely to get dropped datagrams with a polling model. You should see what happens in Perfmon to CPU usage when you poll - you either poll fast enough not to miss anything and send CPU usage through the roof, or poll every now and then and miss half your data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't understand your description of the HoloLens constraint. If it requires UWP, I don't see how you're integrating that with Unity3d at all. Also, your question seems bordering on "too broad". That said…

As far as the implementation question goes, I would prefer the async API regardless. Even if you're stuck on C# 2.0, there is `BeginReceiveFrom()`, and you can copy datagram into a synchronized queue from the asynchronous callback, for processing in your main `Update()` loop in Unity3d. You are less likely to experience dropped datagrams, as well as stuttering in the main Unity3d render loop.